# Detect multiple files at subfolder containing specific string on Linux

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have multiple files of work.log at different subfolders need to detect two keyword `Can't find file` or `Not pass by number`

Direct path like :

```
/folder/Date/Job1/20190116_ADMtest_1/ADM.log
/folder/Date/Job1/20190122_ADMtest_2/ADM.log
/folder/Date/Job1/20190203_ADMtest_4/ADM.log
/folder/Date/Job1/20190217_ADMtest_3/ADM.log
/folder/Date/Job1/20190218_ADMtest_21/ADM.log
/folder/Date/Job1/20190225_ADMtest_18/ADM.log
```

In every log will look like:

```
[Message] 2019-01-16 11:13:21      Read 2 files from: 20190116_ADMtest_1txt
[Message] 2019-01-16 11:13:21
[Message] 2019-01-16 11:13:21      FATAL ERROR:Can't find file
[ERROR] 2019-01-16 11:13:21     ERROR Message : Stop
```

or like

```
[Message] 2019-01-22 10:56:06      #    LOG      1 867 | Runtime: 0 hours 15 minutes and 45 seconds.
[Message] 2019-01-22 10:56:06      #    Message     1 867 |
[Message] 2019-01-22 10:56:06      #    Message     2 152 |
[Message] 2019-01-22 10:56:06      Average number: 58.534678
[ERROR] 2019-01-22 10:56:06     The file failed average number: Average number = 58.534678
```

I want to get a list to know which subfolders have ErrorI `Can't find file` and which subfolders have ErrorII `Not pass by number`

Desire Output like :

```
ErrorI.txt
20190116_ADMtest_1 
20190203_ADMtest_4
20190225_ADMtest_18

ErrorII.txt
20190122_ADMtest_2
20190217_ADMtest_3
20190218_ADMtest_21
```

Comment: Something like `grep -l "msg" /folder/Date/Job1/*/ADM.log`?

Comment: ... or recursively on the parent directory e.g. `grep -rl 'message' /folder/Date/Job1/`

Comment: Can you add an example of the second error? I don't see `Not pass by number` anywhere in your examples. And what should happen if a file has both errors? Should it be listed twice? Will all files be named `ADM.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script that searches for the two strings you mention (note that the second string isn't actually present in your examples) and creates two output files, one for each error, with the list of matching directories:

```sh
## Delete any already existing output files
rm error1.txt error2.txt 2>/dev/null; 

## define the error strings to search for
error1="Can't find file"
error2="Not pass by number"

## Iterate over all AMP.log files
for f in /folder/Date/Job1/*/AMP.log; do 
 if grep -q "$error1" "$f"; then 
  printf '%s\n' "${f%/*}" >> error1.txt
 elif grep -q "$error2" "$f"; then 
  printf '%s\n' "${f%/*}" >> error2.txt 
 fi
done
```

I tested using these example input files:

```
$ for f in folder/Date/Job1/20190*/*log; do echo "===== $f ===="; cat "$f"; done
===== folder/Date/Job1/20190116_ADMtest_1/AMP.log ====
Can't find file
===== folder/Date/Job1/20190122_ADMtest_2/AMP.log ====
Not pass by number
===== folder/Date/Job1/20190203_ADMtest_4/AMP.log ====
Not pass by number
===== folder/Date/Job1/20190217_ADMtest_3/AMP.log ====
Can't find file
===== folder/Date/Job1/20190218_ADMtest_21/AMP.log ====
Can't find file
===== folder/Date/Job1/20190225_ADMtest_18/AMP.log ====
Not pass by number
```

And got the following two output files:

```
$ cat error1.txt 
/folder/Date/Job1/20190116_ADMtest_1
/folder/Date/Job1/20190217_ADMtest_3
/folder/Date/Job1/20190218_ADMtest_21

$ cat error2.txt 
/folder/Date/Job1/20190122_ADMtest_2
/folder/Date/Job1/20190203_ADMtest_4
/folder/Date/Job1/20190225_ADMtest_18
```

Comment: It's work well!!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` ... In as automatic and as efficient (*hard combination*) as I could think of at the moment ... Maybe this is what you need:

```bash
{
declare -A e=( [ErrorI]="Can't find file" [ErrorII]="Not pass by number" )

for i in "${!e[@]}"; do
  grep -rlm1 "${e[$i]}" /folder/Date/Job1/ |
  awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' > "${i}.txt"
  done
}
```

It will create two files: `ErrorI.txt` and `ErrorII.txt` in the current working directory with content like:

```
$ cat ErrorI.txt
20190116_ADMtest_1 
20190203_ADMtest_4
20190225_ADMtest_18

$ cat ErrorII.txt
20190122_ADMtest_2
20190217_ADMtest_3
20190218_ADMtest_21
```